# Why Vader outmaneuver his own things?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/synopsis)

> Vader and his two wingmen easily **outmaneuver** the Y-Wings.

Actually before paragraph it says:

> Vader notices Dutch and **his Y-Wing** group

Here, **his Y-wing** means Y-wing belongs to him (Vader).

Why Vader outmaneuver his own things?

Comment: -1 for using the slang ***para***. If you ask a question, don't use such slang. Write the word out. If the OP edits the question to write out this word, let him or leave a comment and I'll retract my downvote.

Comment: downvote retracted

Answer (score 7):

The Y-wings don't belong to Vader, but to Dutch.

The sentence is ambiguous because "his" could refer to either Vader or Dutch.

When you are writing, you should try to make it clear who or what a pronoun is referring to.

Sometimes it's clear because, for example, we say "his" and there is only one male in context that this could refer to. Like, "Bob gave Sally his book." Clearly "his" refers to Bob because if it was Sally's book we would say "her". (Assuming there's no other male in context.)

Sometimes we make reasonable assumptions based on our general knowledge of the world. "The doctor examined the patient with his X-ray machine." We assume that "his" refers to the doctor, because we don't expect the patient to bring medical equipment for the doctor to use. If the normal assumptions a reader is likely to make aren't valid, you should use words that make it clear.

In this case, there are a couple of clues. The biggest is that, from what I recall of Star Wars, Vader was on the Imperial side and "Y-wings" were a type of fighter used by the rebels. So it would be unlikely that Vader would have a squadron of Y-wings under his command.

Second, even if I didn't know this, it says that "Vader noticed Dutch and his Y-wing group." Vader is noticing two things: one: Dutch, and two: "his Y-wing group". It seems likely that Dutch and the Y-wing group are related to each other. Further, it seems unlikely that Vader would "notice" his own people. Doesn't he know they are there? And it would be odd to group his friends and his enemies together under one "notice". Not impossible: I suppose you could say, "He saw the enemy attacking and his own reinforcements arriving."

Comment: Also, relative proximity is worth mentioning.

Comment: Extremes crop up in the *Biggles* stories of Capt. WE Johns, one of the most prolific; once one of the best-read English writers

Dozens of his books used "Vader notices Dutch and his, Dutch's, Wing…”

Of "he" and a different "him", Johns penned Biggles fighting Fritz as "Biggles punched him, Fritz.”

Clarifications meant so much more than clear writing, he even linked them!

"Biggles saw Fritz and Algy fighting for his, Algy's, gun and punched him, Fritz."

John's, might even say: "Biggles saw Fritz and Algy fighting for his, Algy's, gun, so he, Biggles, hit him, Fritz."